# How to force SQL parameter instead of constant in Expression predicate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-expressions

I want to create predicate expression so that it translates into WHERE clause with SQL parameter, e.g.:

```sql
WHERE e.Id = @id_1;
```

I have this code

```cs
int id = 1;
Expression<Func<Entity, int>> keySelector = e => e.Id;
BinaryExpression equals = Expression.Equal(
   keySelector.Body, 
   Expression.Constant(id, keySelector.Body.Type)); //replace this with a variable

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(equals, keySelector.Parameters[0]);
```

but it translates into:

```sql
WHERE e.Id = 1;
```

which generates new query execution plan for each id.

Does EF core provide some internal mechanism, that I could (should) use, e.g. special subclass of Expression, or ExpressionVisitor?

Answer (score 2):

> Does EF core provide some internal mechanism, that I could (should) use, e.g. special subclass of Expression, or ExpressionVisitor?

Nothing special. All you need is to emulate C# closure. This could be done in several ways - using anonymous type, concrete type, `Tuple` or even real C# compiler generated closure like

```cs
int id = 1;
Expression<Func<int>> valueSelector = () => id;
var value = valueSelector.Body; // use this in place of Expression.Constant
```

Example of anonymous type approach

```cs
int id = 1;
var variable = new { id };
var value = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(variable), nameof(id));
```

Similar with `new Tuple<int>(id)` and `Item1`.